# Rewrite condition not kicking in - Apache mod-rewrite based on existence of a query string -

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have a requirement where if a link has a particular querystring parameter then it should be intercepted and redirected to another url
My current config looks like this

```
<IfModule rewrite_module>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteLog /cfp/apps/t/ts/x/logs/mod_rewrite.log
RewriteLogLevel 9
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} /link_source/
RewriteRule (link_source=email) http://dev1.domain.net:12080/m [R]
</IfModule>
```

My test url is this

```
http://dev1.domain.net/web/messages/7029?link_source=email
```

i expect this url to be caught by this rule(because link_source exists as a query string) and redirected to the new url however that doesn't seem to be happening

On the rewrite logs this is what I see

```
102.2.81.95 - - [25/Jun/2014:13:41:18 --0400] [devash-ecfpwb01.svr.us.jpmchase.net/sid#d625588][rid#d7aec60/initial] (2) init rewrit
e engine with requested uri /a/messages/7029
102.2.81.95 - - [25/Jun/2014:13:41:18 --0400] [devash-ecfpwb01.svr.us.jpmchase.net/sid#d625588][rid#d7aec60/initial] (3) applying pa
ttern '(link_source=email)' to uri '/a/messages/7029'
102.2.81.95 - - [25/Jun/2014:13:41:18 --0400] [devash-ecfpwb01.svr.us.jpmchase.net/sid#d625588][rid#d7aec60/initial] (1) pass through /a/messages/7029
```

Why is this rule not coming into effect and also from the logs it prints the url minus the request params.Is there a way to enable the logging of the query params on the request.

Please help

Comment: `/` means nothing in mod_rewrite. it's ASSUMED that you're using a regex pattern, so `/` is not a pattern delimiter, it's just a slash. So you're saying look for text that looks like a `/` followed by an `l` followed by an `i` etc...

Comment: Thx Marc your answer helped too.Appreciate the quick response

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The syntax is not quite right. Change your condition and rule to this:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} link_source=email
RewriteRule ^ http://dev1.domain.net:12080/m?
```